# Unity Facebook SDK v5.1 cannot login on android device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, facebook-login, facebook-unity-sdk

I get the trouble with using Facebook SDK on android. Below is what I have done:

1. I'm using Facebook sdk 5.1.0 and Unity version is 4.3.4
2. In `Assets\Facebook\Editor\android\FacebookAndroidUtil.cs`, I add
   `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOMEDRIVE")` in line 62
   so that "Debug Android Key Hash" can be generated.
3. I using C# to type the main script, in "Awake()" I add
   `FB.Init(SetInit, InitCallback);`. It just like the tutorial from
   developers.facebook.com, and enable is give out "true". (I think
   that mean `FB.init()` is success.)

After that, I build up a GUI button for log in. I have try `FB.Login("basic_infos", AfterLogin);`, `FB.Login("publish_actions", AfterLogin);` and `FB.Login("email", AfterLogin);` , both the `FB.isLoggedIn` is false on android device.

Actually I can log in on unity environment using "User Access Token". On android device, after I press the Login button, it give out a permission and then I press "OK", nothing happen...(`FB.isLoggedIn` still false)

Anyone can give a help? I get the trouble a few week already...
p.s. My English is not good, please let me know if you don't understand.

Comment: Try using logcat when developing for android. Easiest way is to install Eclipse, go to Window->Show view->Other expand Android and select Logcat. Then setup filters for your application package and tags "Unity", "FBUnitySDK" and "fb4a". This way you can really see whats going on. Check "fb4a" and you will probably find a reason why the login failed.